# Adding more than one yrange on the left hand side of the plot using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to add more then one yrange on the left hand side of the plot using gnuplot?
See the figure linked below, please.

[image]

Ideally I would need yrange commands such as y3range, y4range, etc.

Using `multiplot` I could not get what I want.

```
set multiplot
set lmargin at scr 0.2
set bmargin at scr 0.1 # fix bottom margin
set grid
set y2range [0:20]
plot x, 2*x axes x1y2  # this is your actual plot

unset grid
set lmargin at scr 0.2
set bmargin at scr 0.15 # fix bottom margin
set yrange [0:20]    # set yrange to the same as y2 in the first plot
set border 0         # switch off all borders except the left   
unset xtics          # switch off the stray xtics
plot -1000 notitle   # plot something outside of the y(2)range
unset multi
```

[image]
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using `multiplot` you basically could "mimic" as many axes as you like.
What about adapting this to your needs? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735565/7295599

Comment: @theozh thank you for the suggestion. With `multiplot` I could not get what I want. I modified the original question, explaining the problem with my usage of `multiplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the yranges accordingly such that the ytics and hence the grid are nicely aligned.
Add an offset to the ytics to tune the distances. Check `help xtics`.

**Code:**

```
### multiple axes
reset session

# common settings for all (sub-)plots
set lmargin at screen 0.15
set bmargin at screen 0.12

set xlabel "my x-title"
set xrange[0:3000]
set grid
set ytics font ",8"

myOffsetY = 0.7

set multiplot
    set ylabel "my 1st y-label" tc rgb "red" offset -2,0
    set yrange [-10:6]
    set ytics -10,2 tc rgb "red" offset 0,0
    plot 0.001*x-10 w l lc rgb "red" notitle

    set xlabel " "
    unset xtics
    unset grid
    set ylabel "my 2nd y-label" tc rgb "green" offset 2,0
    set yrange [-10.0:-2.0]
    set ytics -10, 1 tc rgb "green" offset 0,-myOffsetY
    set format y "%.1f"
    plot 0.002*x -10w l lc rgb "green" notitle

    set ylabel "my 3rd y-label" tc rgb "blue" offset -4,0
    set yrange [-60:20]
    set ytics -60, 10 tc rgb "blue" offset 0,myOffsetY
    set format y "%.0f"
    plot 0.003*x-10 w l lc rgb "blue" notitle

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had missed  the usage of `ytics`.